# Two dimension array processing

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to put data in javascript array like below.

```
"Carl", 56
"Mark", 7
"Bob", 45
```

How can I add item and removed from it when I pass any id to that array it should remove that item from array. and gives comma separated names and ids.
I am bit confused about it.

Comment: Removing the jquery tag since the question is not related to jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All objects in JavaScript can be used as associative arrays. You do not need a two-dimensional array for your example.

```
var data = {};
data["Carl"] = 56;
data["Mark"] = 7;
data["Bob"] = 45;
```

To remove an element, use the `delete` keyword:

```
delete data["Carl"];
```

You can iterate over the object using a `for-in` loop. To generate a list, you can do something like this:

```
var result = '';
for (var x in data) {
  if (data.hasOwnProperty(x)) {
    result += x + ',' + data[x] + '\n';
  }
}
alert(result);
```

Comment: Cann't I do something with using id to remove from array? Because while deleting from array I want to remove using id.

Comment: @Keyur: Then maybe you want to store it backwards, using the id as the key and name as the value, like `data[56] = "Carl"`

Comment: But one more thing want to ask you that.. while adding new item into array.. Is there any way to check to remove duplicates or it will not add if key already exists in array??

Comment: @Keyur: It will replace an existing entry with the same key.